# standalone application for WCF

Tags: c#, .net, linux, wcf, iis

I want to host a game's server on Linux - Debian8 (a VPS), but I'm having a problem: the game is written in C# and needs IIS to host the WCF part of it, which doesn't work on Linux.

Someone told me that it is possible to host a server on Debian but I should create a WCF stand-alone app.

How can I do that?

[Here](https://github.com/OpenNos/OpenNos/tree/master/OpenNos.WCF.Interface) can you find server files which use WCF.

Could you help me with this? thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669003/hosting-wcf-service-on-linux Should help you

Comment: I saw this but i don't know what should i change to make it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need IIS

[Hosting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can host in a Service console app

Comment: but how can i create this app? I'm not good at it.

Comment: SO is not a coding service

Comment: I understend....but if I edit Shturm's code by changing "file names" could it work?