# Wcf service host to linux

Tags: linux, windows, wcf, mono, onesignal

I want a bridge between my windows application and php on Linux based API, for that created i need to host my wcf service on Linux OS just because of open source platform. Is this possible with any way?

If hosting is possible then How to create functionality that WCF service push data to my windows application.

If WCF hosting is not possible then is their any thing exist which is replacement of [ONE SIGNAL](https://onesignal.com/) so that i can push notification to my windows application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669003/hosting-wcf-service-on-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting WCF service on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669003/hosting-wcf-service-on-linux)